# How do I install wordpress and drupal together in mamp server

Tags: wordpress, drupal, mamp, drupal-9

I have a developed website already in wordpress, now i want to install drupall and develope another website with. How can I keep my worpdress site and intsall the drupal too?, these two are in same directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webroot for both is bad, because both use **same files like index.php**

Maybe try this:

**Wordpress:** /htdocs/wordpress/webroot/

**Drupal:** /htdocs/wordpress/webroot/**drupalwebroot**/

*So Drupal is in a **subfolder** (drupalwebroot) from wordpress.*

You can use Drupal in a **subfolder** instead of full domain. Example shows backend urls:

- localhost.test/wp-admin/
- localhost.test/**drupalwebroot**/admin/